# C++ Memory leaks in a linked list (Valgrind)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I've been working through some memory leaks on my linked list:
(Currently edited 3+ times, near the bottom)

Here are the errors:

```
==348== HEAP SUMMARY:
==348==     in use at exit: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==348==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 15 frees, 272 bytes allocated
==348== 
==348== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==348==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==348==    by 0x400A2A: RangeSet::RangeSet() (RangeSet.cpp:14)
==348==    by 0x4013ED: main (TestRange.cpp:16)
==348== 
==348== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==348==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==348==    by 0x400F54: RangeSet::Union(RangeSet const&, RangeSet const&) (RangeSet.cpp:167)
==348==    by 0x401400: main (TestRange.cpp:17)
```

I can tell from the similar questions posted that it is most likely a problem I am freeing the "next" pointer, but I went through and fixed those errors (at least I attempted to) and now I only get this (^) from running valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes

Relevant Code:

```
RangeSet::RangeSet()
{
  // make a dummy node?
  RNode* newNode = new RNode();
  head = newNode;
  head->start = 0;
  head->end = 0;
  head->next = NULL; // newing this for memory leak??
  len=0;
} // end of constructor

// copy constructor for Union
RangeSet::RangeSet(const RangeSet &in)
{
  RNode* cur;
  RNode* nex;
  head = new RNode();
  head->start = in.head->start;
  head->end   = in.head->end;
  cur = head;
  nex = in.head->next;

  while (nex){
    cur->next = new RNode();
    cur = cur->next;
    cur->start = nex->start;
    cur->end = nex->end;

    nex = nex->next;
  }
  len = in.len;
} // end of copy constructor


// creates a pointer to new RangeSet that is the union of the two supplied RangeSets
RangeSet* RangeSet::Union(const RangeSet &alpha, const RangeSet &beta)
{
  // alpha and beta are const, so create copy
  RangeSet* copAlpha = new RangeSet(alpha);
  RNode *cursor = beta.head;
  // addRange all of beta into alpha's copy
  while (cursor != NULL){
    copAlpha->addRange(cursor->start, cursor->end);
    cursor=cursor->next;
  }
  return copAlpha;
} // end of Union
```

Could the problem be my RNode's constructor?

```
struct RNode {
  int start, end;
  RNode* next;
  // possibly a pointer back to make it doubly linked
  RNode() {
    next = NULL;
  } 
};
```

**EDIT**
Sorry! Here's my delete function (my destructor just calls it):

```
// makes the set empty
void RangeSet::deleteAllElements() 
{
 // having memory leak problems stemming from this function
 // trying to fix
  RNode *nex = head->next;
  for (RNode* cursor = head; cursor; cursor=nex){
    nex = cursor->next;
    RNode *cur = cursor;
    delete(cur);
    //delete(cursor->next); // Should I do this in a constructor for the RNode
    len--;
  }

} // end of deleteAllElements
```

**EDIT 2**
Updating with addRange and sort (called by addRange at the end). Thank you all for your continued help! (Sorry that addRange is somewhat lengthy and probably convoluted)

```
// addRange
void RangeSet::addRange(int rangeStart, int rangeEnd)
{
  // debug                  
  //cout << "Adding range: " << rangeStart << " to " << rangeEnd << endl;

  // li'l bit of error checking
  if (rangeStart > rangeEnd){
    cerr << "Please enter range(s) in the correct order. Exiting." << endl;
    exit(0);         
  }

  // head case
  if (len==0){
    head->start = rangeStart;
    head->end = rangeEnd;
    len++;
  // need to account for adding at beginning
  } else if (rangeStart <= head->start){
       //cout << "INSERTING AT BEGINNING" << endl;
       RNode *newNode = new RNode();                 
       newNode->start = head->start;             
       newNode->end   = head->end;  
       newNode->next  = head->next;
       head->start = rangeStart; 
       head->end   = rangeEnd;
       head->next  = newNode;                 
       len++;                 
   } else if (head->next == NULL){
       RNode *newNode = new RNode();
       newNode->start = rangeStart;
       newNode->end = rangeEnd;   
       head->next = newNode;
       len++;                 
   } else {
       // Moving past any nodes where the start is less than rangeStart
       RNode *cursor = head;
       RNode *past = cursor;
       int count = 1;
       while (cursor!=NULL && count<=len){
         if (rangeStart > cursor->start){
           //cout << rangeStart << " is > than " << cursor->start << endl;
           //cout << "DEBUG1(cursor): " << cursor->start << endl;
           //cout << "DEBUG2(past): " << past->start << endl;   
           past = cursor;
           cursor = cursor->next;
         }  
         count++;
      }
       //cout << "INSERTING POS: " << count <<  endl;
       // creating a new node to insert in middle
       RNode *newNode = new RNode();
       newNode->start = rangeStart;
       newNode->end   = rangeEnd;
       if (count == 1){       
         // add it after head (no other nodes)
         head->next = newNode;
         newNode->next = NULL;    
       } else {
         if (cursor){              
           newNode->next = cursor;
         }                  
         past->next = newNode;
       }   
       len++;
   }

  //dump();          
  sort();
} // end addRange
```

So what I do is I create the new node and add it into the list based on its starting value, then I call sort():

```
// sort function called by addRange
void RangeSet::sort()
{
  //cout << "SORTING" << endl;   
  RNode *cursor = head;
  while (cursor->next != NULL){
    RNode *curPlusOne = cursor->next;
    if (cursor->end >= (curPlusOne->start -1)){
      if (cursor->end < curPlusOne->end){
        cursor->end = curPlusOne->end;
      }
      cursor->next = curPlusOne->next;
      //cout << "NODE BEING DELETED: " << curPlusOne->start << " to " << curPlusOne->end << endl;
      delete(curPlusOne);
      len--;
    } else {
      cursor=cursor->next;
    }
  } // end while
  //dump();
} // end sort
```

**EDIT 3** Posting my main and my deleteRange. I also got a different set of errors this time around that I'll post towards the bottom. Thanks again!

```
// deletes all integers from RANGESTART to RANGEEND inclusive
void RangeSet::deleteRange(int rangeStart, int rangeEnd)
{
  RNode *cursor = head;
  RNode *past = cursor;
  RNode *temp = cursor->next;
  while (cursor){
    temp = cursor->next;
    if (rangeStart <= cursor->start && rangeEnd >= cursor->end){
    // case 1: if the entire node is encompassed by what is being deleted
      if (cursor==head) { // still at head
        head = head->next;
        past = cursor;
        delete(cursor);
      } else {
        past->next = cursor->next;
        delete(cursor);
      }
      len--;

    } else if (rangeStart<=cursor->start && rangeEnd>=cursor->start && rangeEnd<=cursor->end) {
    // case 2: the rangeStart is smaller than node's rangeStart
      cursor->start = rangeEnd+1; 
      len--;

    } else if (rangeEnd>=cursor->end && rangeStart>=cursor->start && rangeStart<=cursor->end) {
    // case 3: the rangeEnd is larger than node's rangeEnd
      cursor->end = rangeStart-1;
      len--;

    } else if (cursor->start < rangeStart && cursor->end > rangeEnd){
    // case 4: the range is in the middle of a node (split)
      RNode *newNode = new RNode();
      newNode->start = rangeEnd+1;
      newNode->end = cursor->end;
      newNode->next = cursor->next;
      cursor->end=rangeStart-1;
      cursor->next = newNode;
      len--;
    }
    past = cursor;
    cursor=temp;
  } // end while
} // end of deleteRange

int main(){
   RangeSet S, T;
   S.addRange(5,10);
   S.addRange(22,33);
   S.addRange(4,6);
   T.addRange(30,35);
   RangeSet U;
   U = *RangeSet::Union(T,S);
   U.addRange(1,1);
   U.addRange(39,40);
   U.addRange(40,150);
   RangeSet B(U);

   if (B==U)
     cout << "COPY CONSTRUCTOR + OVERLOADED OPERATOR WORKED!" << endl;
   U.dump();
   cout << endl;
   U.deleteRange(1,35);
   U.deleteRange(75,100);
   U.dump();
}
```

Here are the new (ish, I was receiving them earlier but I thought I had fixed them) errors I am receiving when I run valgrind:

```
==22482== Invalid read of size 8
==22482==    at 0x40122D: RangeSet::deleteAllElements() (RangeSet.cpp:237)
==22482==    by 0x400B79: RangeSet::~RangeSet() (RangeSet.cpp:47)
==22482==    by 0x401524: main (TestRange.cpp:30)
==22482==  Address 0x5a03368 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==22482==    at 0x4C2A4BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22482==    by 0x401261: RangeSet::deleteAllElements() (RangeSet.cpp:241)
==22482==    by 0x400B79: RangeSet::~RangeSet() (RangeSet.cpp:47)
==22482==    by 0x401500: main (TestRange.cpp:30)
```

This is why I thought my problem had to lie within deleteAllElements, but I'm still stumped!

**EDIT 4** Just a note, the main function is adapted from a skeleton provided to me, so I can't do too much to change it if therein lies the problem.

Comment: You didn't show any code that deletes the nodes. You say you added code for that, but you didn't include it here. Chances are there is something wrong in that code (or it's not called for all the nodes).

Comment: Are there any code calling `delete`?

Comment: What does `addRange` look like?

Comment: if you can, post the implementations of `addRange`, `RangeSet::~RangeSet` and `main`

Comment: when you copy a RangeSet, you set the start and end of the new set to be the start and end of the old set, don't you want to set them to be the start and end of the newly created copy set? surely you don't want one Set's start and end referencing nodes of another set?

Comment: @matt `start` and `end` are `int`s, not pointers. Not sure what they're used for, but there's a good chance that's safe.

Comment: @matt start and end are integer, I'm guessing representing a "range", the `RangeSet` being a list of integer ranges. That threw me off as well for a bit. They have nothing to do with the list nodes.

Comment: in addRange, I cant see how it would be possible that in the final big else, len could be less than or equal to 1, or that head could be the only node, you check that above in one of the other elseifs

Comment: what is the test code you are running?

Comment: There are certainly some areas for improvement, but nothing's jumping out as a leak. I agree with previous commenters that you should post the rest of the code (specifically `main` and the destructor).

Comment: My destructor just calls deleteAllElements, which should also take care of the head, right? Those were my intentions, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U = *RangeSet::Union(T,S);

that line!! that one there!!!

you are copying the returned value, then just disregarding the returned value which is a pointer to an allocation, hence the allocation never gets freed.

What you want to do is go:

```
RangeSet* t = RangeSet::Union(T,S);
U = *t; // copy the returned value stored on the heap, into local varaible U not stored on the heap
delete t; // delete the returned value that is stored on the heap
```

OK, what I think you should do in your case is change Union to this:

```
void Union(const RangeSet &alpha, const RangeSet &beta, RangeSet &result)
    {
      // alpha and beta are const, so create copy
      result = RangeSet(alpha);
      RNode *cursor = beta.head;
      // addRange all of beta into alpha's copy
      while (cursor != NULL){
        result.addRange(cursor->start, cursor->end);
        cursor=cursor->next;
      }

    }
```

then simply change your line in main to be:
    `RangeSet::Union(T,S,U);`

Comment: If I put

delete(&U);

at the end of main, valgrind gives me:

==22574== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

Comment: no, then you are trying to delete the address of local variable U, which was not an allocation.

Comment: Can I modify Union so that the above line (in main, that was provided to me) works correctly?

Comment: did someone really give you the line:  U = *RangeSet::Union(T,S); ? or was it U = RangeSet::Union(T,S);

Comment: That line (the former) was in the small skeleton of a main driver given to us by the Professor.

However, after what you provided... it works perfectly... no memory leaks...

Comment: Dear lord... I can't imagine how anyone could make a `Union` function where `RangeSet U = *RangeSet::Union(T,S);` didn't result in a memory leak (well I can, but it would be a stupid pointless thing to do unless that was the specific challenge :P )

Comment: Union() should return the result by value. (http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Comment: @JohnSmith Did you explicitly define the assignment operator? I ask because while it's a good idea, it wasn't part of the code you posted. If you didn't, since this solution solved your problem, it seems your compiler is skipping the call to the default constructor and calling the copy constructor instead (which would have be expected had you done `RangeSet U = *RangeSet::Union(T,S);`).